# factory pattern - avoid type specific condition

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

Please help me how can I skip these conditions?

I am using factory pattern.

```
pizza = pizzaFctory.create ('xxx'); # e.g. these types are a,b,c,d
```

now I call a function

```
pizza->verifySomething ('yyy');
```

Here is my question:
  the argument 'foo' is different for different types (a,b,c,d). e.g. if argument to `create()` is 'a' then argument to `verifySomething` 'fooa'. Similarly, if argument to `create()` is 'b' then argument to `verifySomething` 'foob'.

I understand that I can put one condition and verify it.

```
  if (pizza->isTypeA)
  {
    pizza->verifySomething ('fooa');
  }
```

I want to avoid this if condition. Please tell me some ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract Pizza
{
    public abstract bool VerifySomething( object obj );
}

public class APizza : Pizza
{
    public bool VerifySomething( object obj )
    {
        FooA foo = (FooA)obj;
        ...
    }
}

public class BPizza : Pizza
{
    public bool VerifySomething( object obj )
    {
        FooB foo = (FooB)obj;
        ...
    }
}
```

If all of the types of pizza can't have a VerifySomething method they you may be violating the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP). There may be a better way to separate your classes that will make this more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the argument for `verifySomething` as property (or a method) of the pizza created, something along these lines (in C#, but it should be understandable)

```
public abstract class Pizza
{
   public abstract string GetParameter();

   public bool VerifySomething1()
   {
      //You can use GetParameter here directly
   }

   public bool VerifySomething2(string parameter)
   {
      //The parameter is passed from the caller
   }
}

public class Capricciosa : Pizza 
{
   public override string GetParameter() {return "CapricciosaParameter";}
}

public class Vezuvio : Pizza
{
   public override string GetParameter() {return "VezuvioParameter";}
}

Pizza pizza = PizzaFactory.Create("Vesuvio");

pizza.VerifySomething1(); //parameter is gotten inside the method
pizza.VerifySomething2(pizza.GetParameter()); //the parameter is explicitly passed
```